# resizing columns width in sap.m.Table

Tags: sapui5

I have a lot of rows in sap.m.table and I want to show all rows' names properly. First I made table auto and gave the columns 100% width and made them demand popin. I tried a lot of combinations but I couldn't manage to show them properly. Here what I've got at the end.
[image]

My view is at the below:

```
<m:ScrollContainer
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    horizontal="true"
    vertical="true"
    focusable="true">
    <m:Table id="idTable"
        inset="false"
        growing="true" 
        growingThreshold="3"
        fixedLayout="false"
        visibleRowCount="7"
        border-collapse="collapse"
        items="{
            path: '/...',
            sorter: {
                path: '...'
            }
        }">
    <m:headerToolbar>
    </m:headerToolbar>
    <m:columns>
        <m:Column
            minScreenWidth="Desktop"
            demandPopin="true"
            width="12em">
            <m:Text text="{i18n>YUKLEME_NO}" />
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column
             minScreenWidth="Desktop"
             demandPopin="true"
             hAlign="Left">
             <m:Text text="{i18n>GEMI_BILGISI}" />
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column
             minScreenWidth="Desktop"
             demandPopin="true"
             width="12em"
             hAlign="Left">
             <m:Text text="{i18n>YUKLEME_ARAC_SAYISI}" />
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column
            minScreenWidth="Desktop"
            demandPopin="true"
            hAlign="Left">
            <m:Text text="{i18n>PROFORMA_NO}" />
        </m:Column>
        ...             
        <m:Column
            demandPopin="true"
            width="14em"
            hAlign="Left">
            <m:Text text="{i18n>MODEL}" />
```

I also tried minScreenWidth="Desktop" and wrapping="true" for columns. But still it didn't change.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Can you set up a small JSBin with your table?

Comment: I couldn't manage to set up. cause I was working with a service and I don't have a time to write an json data sorry for that but thank you for your interest. For now, I avoided from this error using width property for each column and set layout to fixed. I also reedited the question for you

Comment: Same issues, I guess because of wrong minScreenWidth settings. Using Small, XSmall, etc instead of Desktop (width=1024) might help...
@TimGerlach Here are two jsbin examples that illustrate the issue:

- [JSBIN: sap.m.Table in an XMLView](https://jsbin.com/mozocepidi/edit?html,output)

- [JSBIN: sap.m.Table in master detail page with sapUiResponsiveContentPadding](https://jsbin.com/cijusegefi/edit?html,output)

The second example seems to cause more issues (also without sapUiResponsiveContentPadding).

ps: why does items="{view>/products}" not work (see code)?

Answer (score 2):

See [sap.m.Column.minScreenWidth](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Column.html#getMinScreenWidth) as well as [Enum sap.m.ScreenSize](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ScreenSize.html).

You are using minScreenWidth="Desktop" for all your columns. That means the columns will look like what you see until your screen width goes below 1024px. You could play around with different combinations of [sap.m.ScreenSize](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ScreenSize.html) for your columns. But you could also use something like minScreenWidth="1280px" instead of using the enum. Furthermore, you could use the width="9em" or what ever value. So basically the issue you described occurs if you have a bad configuration for your column's minScreenWidth properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not thinking of going mobile this particular scenario, I would suggest you to go to for [sap.ui.table.Table](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/Table.html#__3).

Sample code:

```
oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    title: "Table with fixed columns Example and scroller",
    visibleRowCount: 7,
    firstVisibleRow: 3,
    selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
    navigationMode: sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator,
    fixedColumnCount: 0
});
```

[Working JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9jzxb3kj/)

Comment: Seems like you gave an width for each column but I am looking for an automatic way to do that. but thank you to share your idea with me :)